# Blur background on ViewPager scroll

Tags: android, image, android-viewpager

I have a `ViewPager`, and I want the background image that I have to blur or at least darken when the user scrolls from the first to the second page. I'm currently using `OnPageChangeListener`, but I'm having trouble figuring out how I can blur or darken programatically without having two copies of the image. Any help would be greatly appreciated!

```
ViewPager pager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.viewpager);
pager.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.kuwaitphotography);
pager.setAdapter(pageAdapter);
pager.setOnPageChangeListener(new OnPageChangeListener() {

@Override
public void onPageScrollStateChanged(int arg0) {}

@Override
public void onPageScrolled(int arg0, float arg1, int arg2) {
// Do something in here?
}

@Override
public void onPageSelected(int arg0) {}});
```

Comment: Can you place a view overlay which gets visible when page scroll starts and hide when finished?

Comment: That's what I was thinking. I have a black background underneath my drawable background, and I was thinking of decreasing the alpha value of the drawable as `arg1` changes. Do you have any idea how to do that?

Comment: You can set the color value of view including alpha like 
android:background="#AA000000". It will make your view show some transparency.

Comment: Is there any way to do the same with a blur effect?